# How is the reliability calculated in Mahout

Tags: classification, mahout

I get the following output from a classification with Mahout:

```
======================================================= 
Summary 
------------------------------------------------------- 
Correctly Classified Instances          :       3948       93,4217%
Incorrectly Classified Instances        :        278        6,5783% 
Total Classified Instances              :       4226 

======================================================= 
Confusion Matrix 
------------------------------------------------------- 
a       b       <--Classified as 
3747    263      |  4010        a     = NOT_Science fiction 
15      201      |  216         b     = Science fiction 

======================================================= 
 Statistics 
------------------------------------------------------- 
Kappa                                       0,5594 
Accuracy                                   93,4217% 
Reliability                                62,1657% 
Reliability (standard deviation)            0,5384
```

How does Mahout calculate the Reliability?

According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-941 it should be the User Accuracy. As I understand the User Accuracy it should calculate for each column the correctly classified instances divided by the total number which were classified by this class. (http://spatial-analyst.net/ILWIS/htm/ilwismen/confusion_matrix.htm)

So far, I cannot figure out how the 62,1657% are calculated.

If I calculate the average of the classes I get the following:
((3747 / 4010) + (201 / 216)) / 2 = 0.932 --> 93.2%

If I calculate the average of the columns I get the following:
((3747 / 3762) + (201 / 464)) / 2 = 0.715 --> 71.5%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reliability is the User Accuracy. It is not correctly calculated in the current version (0.9).

```
public RunningAverageAndStdDev getNormalizedStats() {
    RunningAverageAndStdDev summer = new FullRunningAverageAndStdDev();
    for(int d = 0; d < confusionMatrix.length; d++) {
        double total = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < confusionMatrix.length; j++) {
            total += confusionMatrix[d][j];
        }
        summer.addDatum(confusionMatrix[d][d] / (total + 0.000001));
    }
    return summer;
}
```

The problem is that the Confusion Matrix consists of all Labels and an additional "DEFAULT" label. It seems the "DEFAULT" label is for unclassified instances. If you have no unclassified instances it disturbs the result. An additional check for the "DEFAULT" Label and it worked for me.

```
public RunningAverageAndStdDev getNormalizedStats() {
RunningAverageAndStdDev summer = new FullRunningAverageAndStdDev();
    for (int d = 0; d < confusionMatrix.length; d++) {

        //Do not add the "DEFAULT" label to the calculation
        if(labelMap.get(defaultLabel) == d)
                continue;

        double total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < confusionMatrix.length; j++) {
            total += confusionMatrix[d][j];
        }
        summer.addDatum(confusionMatrix[d][d] / (total + 0.000001));
    }
    return summer;
}
```